# AngularJS $http success but not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

i'm using angularJS and SLIM PHP restful server, the PHP service is working and actually i have already used $http.get() with no problems in this application ... 
But now a strange thing is happening, i created a new function in the same way that the others, and it get .success(function(data)) with no problems, i actually can console.log(data) and it shows the right results, but when .success() finish and return, i recieve a undefined result.
ps: there is no error in browser console.

```
    var markerOptions = [];
    loadMarkers();
    console.log(markerOptions);

    function loadMarkers() {
    $http.get('http://localhost/rest/getMarkers').success(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            markerOptions = response;
    });
}
```

- Console.log() inside success() return the right data
- Console.log() after loadMarkers() return undefined

Comment: Since `$http.get` is asynchronous, its results are not available immediately where your synchronous code picks up. This is why your `console.log` is empty outside of `success`.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: BTW, this is a very common painpoint that is well-worth the headache of wrapping your head around once and for all.

Comment: humm, i get it, thank you very much Marc. I'm trying to realise a solution for this in angular now.. but you show me the path, ty again.

Comment: The top answer in the article above is great as a primer, and then you can read the [documentation on `$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) in Angular for more food for thought.

Answer (score 4):

@MarcKline's comments are correct. Anyways, following what I think you're trying to achive by this piece of code of yours, you can assign the returned data from the ajax response to a scope variable (assuming you're using $scope), e.g `$scope.markerOptions = response`. You can declare markOptions as a scope variable by `var $scope.markOptions = []` (...and, of course, log it by `console.log($scope.markOptions)` accordingly). Also, define `$scope.loadMarkers = function() {...}` and call it by `$scope.loadMarkers()`

The scope will be updated as soon as the client-side gets its ajax response.
Hope it helps your current needs in addition to a better understanding of javasciprt's async approach that some of its principles were explained to you by the comments.

Comment: I try it, and doesn't work, i try use  .then() too ... but still not working :(

Comment: define loadMarkers as a scope function by $scope.loadMarkers = function() {...} and call it by `$scope.loadMarkers()`